# Is it true that if $G$ is a connected graph then $χ(G) \leq 1 + av(G)$?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Is it true that if $G$ is a connected graph then $χ(G) \leq 1 + av(G)$?

$av(G)$ is the average of the vertex degrees in $G$ and $χ(G)$ is the chromatic number of $G$. Give a proof if it's true, or give a counter example if it's false.

Intuitively I think this is true, but I don't know how to start on the proof. Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untrue. Take for example a $K_5$ and attach a very long path to it. This will have $av(G)\approx 2$ with $\chi(G)=5$.

Comment: Why is $av(G)$ $\approx 2$? Shouldn't it be 5 for a $K_5$ graph?

Comment: @user59036 Sean English said "attach a very long path to it [$K_5$]."

Comment: @Batominovski  Since each of the vertex in this very long path has a degree 2, eventually the average degree will be reduced to 2 approximately 2?

Comment: @user59036 exactly!

Comment: @SeanEnglish Thank you for the help!